# Lookback API Displaying Old field name for the Custom Feild

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

We are facing a strange issue with the Look-back API.
We have created a Custom field initially as xyz, back end name c_xyz for the features. 
After few days we renamed the Custom attribute to abc which in-turn changed the back-end name to c_abc, which was an expected behavior.

However , the Lookback API still gives the old field name c_xyz in the result set of that object till we actually make an update via UI/API on the abc(c_abc) attribute. Is there any way we can workaround this, apart from updating the particular value.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, no.  Responding to field name changes in this way would be a big performance hit.